# jQuery Animation on Navigation

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having troubles with jQuery animation running twice on my navigation bar.  Mouse over once causes it to fly down then back up.  It won't stay visible.  Mousing over twice gives the right effect.  Here is how the Nav is set up:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="en.about.html">About<img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt=""/></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="en.accreditations.html">Accreditations</a></li>
      <li><a href="en.partnerships.html">Partnerships</a></li>
      <li><a href="en.labs.html">Laboratories</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Industries</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
...
</ul>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').ready(function() {
$('li').hover(function() {
$(this).find('li').slideToggle(); 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: neither can we visualize your jquery animation

Comment: see Eran's answer, your code lack of precision.  $('li') covers all of the li on your page which is probably why you see the double animation. because you trigger one hover on the main li then you trigger a unhover on the li inside of the actual nav items. So hopefully Eran's answer will guide you towards the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrwte/15/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav" style="width:200px">
<ul style="border:1px solid red">
  <li class="topMenuItem"><a href="en.about.html">About<img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt=""/></a>
    <ul style="display:none">
      <li><a href="en.accreditations.html">Accreditations</a></li>
      <li><a href="en.partnerships.html">Partnerships</a></li>
      <li><a href="en.labs.html">Laboratories</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Industries</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**
    ​

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.topMenuItem').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    });

    $('.topMenuItem').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    });
​});
```

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming this is for a dropdown menu?

I would assume you would want to make the whole list slide, not just a list item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('li').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(); 
        });
    });

</script>
```

Tho, if you are wanting them to hide on mouse out...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('li').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').slideDown(); 
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp(); 
        });
    });

</script>
```

Or who knows, I could be completely miss reading your question.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: the 2nd one looks great, I think this is what the OP meant, see my answer for a working example in JSFiddle

Comment: @Cameron, yes it's for a dropdown.  The code is working, it just seems  that you have to hover twice for it to act like its supposed to do.  I think that maybe multiple uses of li or ul are causing it to jump around a bit.

Comment: @Ben - I think giving everything either a name or a class is more explicit and makes things more clear, a working solution (in JSFiddle) in my answer below, but Cameron's answer is correct in general.

Comment: @EranMedan - Thanks for the welcome. I've used this site forever and finally decided I would give back to the community. Thanks for the JSFiddle example. I forgot all about that or I would have done it.

Comment: @EranMedan and Cameron  thank you for your help!  I'm pretty new to using jQuery, and adding the classes to each top menu item seems to do the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. not to hint anything, but if you want, you can do a few things to show your thanks - best one: pay it forward and answer other people's questions in SO, also it's nice to mark one of the answers here as your accepted answer, or vote up / down answers you think are good / bad

Comment: @EranMedan will do.  Never expected an answer back today!

Comment: @Ben more then welcome man! We love being helpful.. and the fact that SO turns it into a game with reputation, makes it even better. Haha =).